# Airflow - List of downstream tasks for a task

Tags: task, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

May I know if there is an airflow command which list all downstream tasks for a task. For example, there are 4 tasks in a dag - dummy1 > dummy2 > dummy3 > dummy4. I need list of all downstream tasks of dummy2, output should be dummy3 and dummy4. If there is a command then it will help if there are many downstream tasks for a task and to do manual actions only on downstream tasks.

Dag - dummy1 > dummy2 > dummy3 > dummy4

Output : (downstream tasks list of dummy2)

dummy3
dummy4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no a CLI command for this, but it is a one-liner in Python.

Let's assume your DAG-script name is `a_dag.py` and the `DAG` object is referenced by the variable `dag`.

Then you can do something like this in the terminal:

```
$ cd airflow/dags 

$ ls
a_dag.py

$ python
Python 3.8.2 ...
>>> from a_dag import dag
>>> dag.get_task('dummy2').get_flat_relative_ids()
{'dummy3', 'dummy4'}
```